# Is there a header manager configuration to solve 422 error in JMeter using Json body?

Tags: json, jmeter, http-headers

My Json body Data in Jmeter HTTP request is:

```
{"someone":[],"customer":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","email":"Someone1@gmail.com","mainClient":true,"document":"1234567","documentType":3,"phone":"+12344567876"}],"hotelId":${hotelId},"hotelRoomTypes":[{"total":1,"hotelRoomTypeId":"${hotelRoomTypes}"}]}
```

I got the message on the response:

```
{"code":422,"message":"api.error.product.Something.available"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON request format is not valid. Check the image:

[image]

I have trialed with a sample test to check if it works when JSON format is valid. Added a CSV data set config element, Dummy sampler and view results tree listener to check. It worked perfectly.

Change `${hotelId}` to `"${hotelId}"` in the JSON request and try again.

CSV file contains `123456` as `hotelId` and passed it to the `Dummy sampler` request using variable call. And found the expected result in `View Results tree` listener.

[image: Dummy Sampler]

[image: View Results Tree]

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks! I Changed  ${hotelId} to "${hotelId}" in the JSON request so and I got the values from CSV data Set Config. But I am still getting an error, right now "{"code":125,"message":"Malformed body","info":{"obj.hotelId":["Number value expected"]"